# How do I get all links of a Wikipedia page, not including the ones in the navbox at the bottom?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I want to get all the links on the Wikipedia page [Charles Maurice de Talleyrand-Périgord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Maurice_de_Talleyrand-P%C3%A9rigord), but without all the links within the navboxes at the bottom of the page. I've been using the links prop (e.g. [https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=query&prop=links&titles=Charles%20Maurice%20de%20Talleyrand-Périgord&pllimit=max](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=query&prop=links&titles=Charles%20Maurice%20de%20Talleyrand-P%C3%A9rigord&pllimit=max)), but it includes the navboxes, and I haven't found another property that pertains to my concern. Is there a way to exclude them?
[image: Navboxes]

Comment: Get all links from the templates, then subtract them from the page.

Comment: The API does not have a method to distinguish the links in the navbox from other links